# Pandas - Groupby, year, week

Tags: pandas, stock

I am stuck with a newbie question.
What I am trying to achieve.

I want to know, when a stock price goes above mondays high and or low, within a specific week.

I am toying around with one week, in the hope to make it possible for all the weeks of multiple years.

Here is what I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib


# Get the S&P ticker
ticker = "^GSPC"
start_date = "2023-05-22"
end_date = "2023-05-28"
# Get the historical stock price data for the S&P 500 for the past week
df = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)

# Remove unused data
df.drop(["Open","Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1 ,inplace=True)
# df.head()

# Adding weekday
df.insert(0, 'Year', df.index.isocalendar().year)
df.insert(1, "Week", df.index.isocalendar().week)
df.insert(2, "Weekday", df.index.day_name())
```

I then thought about grouping everything by year and week. `dfWeek = df.groupby(["Year","Week"])` 
In the hope that I can go to each "week" and then extend the data with additional rows, where the conditions are meet.

But here I am somehow stuck and do not know how to procced.

`MondayHighTakenOut`, where df.High > df[df["Weekday"] =="Monday"].High[0], for the first occurrence.
`MondayLowTakenOut`, where df.Low < df[df["Weekday"] =="Monday"].Low[0], , for the first occurrence.

Any help or tutorial is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's  a little unclear what you are looking to achieve. It would help if you provided a specific example of input data and the output you are looking for.